# Generating unique permutations

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to generate unique permutations of length two from a string but I'm getting repeated values. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code:

```
a = 'abba'
from itertools import permutations
x = []
x = [y for y in list(permutations(a,2)) if y not in x]
'''
output was this:
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'),('b', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b')]
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list comprehension builds a list, *then* assigns it to `x`, so `x == []` the whole time it's running. Every time the list comprehension checks `y not in x`, *`x` is still an empty list*, so of course `y` is never in it.

If order isn't crucial, you could use a `set` instead:

```
x = set(permutations(a, 2))
```

Otherwise, unroll the list comprehension:

```
x = []
for y in permutations(a, 2):
    if y not in x:
        x.append(y)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Could you explain plz? :3

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I understand that it first builds a list and then assigns it to x but what does it has to do with those duplicates? :|

Comment: Because every time the list comprehension checks `y not in x`, *`x` is still an empty list*.